# Field dropping in knockout JS

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am facing an issue with binding data to multiple fields using knockout js.
I found out this code to be responsible for it. This code is not written by me, so couldn't understand the reason behind.
Can anyone explain this?

```
ko.bindingHandlers.isolatedOptions = {
//element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext
init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var args = arguments;
    ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            ko.bindingHandlers.options.update.apply(this, args);
        },
        owner: this,
        disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved: element
    });
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor)
{
    var args = arguments;
    ko.computed({
        read: function ()
        {
            ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            ko.bindingHandlers.options.update.apply(this, args);
        },
        owner: this,
        disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved: element
    });
}};
```

This is how it is use:

```
<select data-bind="isolatedOptions: $root.procurementTypes, optionsText: 'Display', optionsValue: 'ItemValue', optionsCaption: 'Select...', value: $data.PROCURE_TY, visible:$root.s1display([6,1])() === 2 && $root.workflowStepDescription().statusCode !== 'NIP'"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is creating custom binding for your html code called isolatedOptions to be used like click, change, value default built in bindings. It must be getting used in your code with data-bind attribute of some HTML element.

Check more here

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

Your element is select and your valueAccessor is $root.procurementTypes. init is called when initial state of element select is being set. It takes the parameter and runs init function. update can be called more than once by knockout js if you are using observables or computed stuff and there is a change. It is called initially at the time of application of bindings also.

Comment: I am facing an issue where the MaterialType field is not getting populated on form load from AJAX

[link]http://jsfiddle.net/n0mrjzf4/
In the fiddle the MaterialTypes is set from Ajax and the set data need to be populated to MaterialType placeholder.

Comment: Basically, it is as good as binding data to a property in knockout. Is it only one field or more. I would suggest raising another question and sharing the code for the same there. That will help to easily identify the root cause.